# sort data in table in descending order of date :react js

Tags: reactjs

I have displayed data of an API in a table form and I am trying to sort the data date wise but I am not getting it correct. If anyone can help me with it, it will be helpful.

```
const groupedByDate = res.data.reduce((meals, meal) => {
          if (meal.date in meals) {
            meals[meal.date].push(meal);
          } else {
            meals[meal.date] = [meal];
          }
          return meals;
        }, {});
        const sortedOnDate = Object.values(groupedByDate).sort((arr1, arr2) => {
          if (arr1[0].date < arr2[0].date) {
            return -1;
          } else if (arr1[0].date > arr2[0].date) {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
        setData(sortedOnDate);
      });
```

I have also added a code sandbox of what I have tried

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-alex-v3xlp?file=/src/App.js:1255-1807)

It will be very helpful if u can edit the sandbox and provide a working example

Comment: that have nothing to do with the sorting. anyway  i have removed the errror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sorted that way because your date format is DD-MM-YYYY
You can sort date if it's in YYY-MM-DD format.

It's a bit hacky but it works in your current codebase.

```
const sortedOnDate = Object.values(groupedByDate).sort((arr1, arr2) => {

      // Convert DD-MM-YYYY into YYYY-MM-DD
      const ymdDate1 = arr1[0].date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
      const ymdDate2 = arr2[0].date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
      if (ymdDate1 < ymdDate2) {
        return -1;
      } else if (ymdDate1 > ymdDate2) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    setData(sortedOnDate);
```

Comment: ur code is working but the date is sorted in accecding order  im looking to sort it in decensing order

Comment: you can swap return -1 and return 1 to get descending order.